# Change list background problem

Tags: android, listview

I have a **ListView** and on clicking a list item, it starts another activity.

So my problem is that, when I click on list item, it should change its background and move to another activity and on pressing back on this activity the list item should retain it changed background color. And again clicking on another list, it should remove the earlier background color and again do the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi sujit i am also facing same problem means i want to change backgroud color on list click..and same as ur problem can u provide me the solution for the same i will be greatly thankfull of you and you will be as my saver(god).vv thanks  email id: saurabh26213@gmail.com

Comment: i have already added my answer below ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by **setItemChecked()** methood and use   **android:choiceMode="singleChoice**" inside ListView in my layout xml file. I used `MyClass.this.getListView().setItemChecked(position,true);` on clicking the Item in the list and the on getView() i am doing this...

```
 if(position == MyClass.this.getListView().getCheckedItemPosition()){

                holder._newsLinear.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
            }
            else{

                holder._newsLinear.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want the `setItemChecked()` method in the ListView. This should make the item you click "permanently on", if you place it in the `onItemClick()` method in a listener. Note that when you navigate to the next activity, you will have to use [`onSaveInstanceState()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) and [`onRestoreInstanceState()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) to store which item in the `ListView` has been clicked; I don't believe Android will retain which one has been clicked when you navigate away from the `Activity` with the `ListView`.

There is quite a good tutorial of this in the Fragments section of the Developers website, [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html#Example).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ...but i have solve it without using onSaveInstanceState() .

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the selected item. Use a custom adapter and override the `getView` method. In this method check if the position of the view is the selected item and change the background of the view accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Override the item click listener and do the following to change the color of the clicked view:

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener()
{    
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2, long arg3)
   {
      v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);                
   }
});
```

Comment: but when we scroll the list it will set black background randomly to the list items.